# Delphi 11. Web Server. local CSS does not render correctly

Tags: css, delphi

I have created a simple web server using tWebModule.  I have created a standalone for testing, and an ISAPI DLL for deployment to IIS.  Both use the same code.  I would like to use local css files in case my app is used where internet is not available.

When I browse to the standalone server, the css does not render correctly.  When I browse to the IIS server, the page renders properly. (see image)

If I use the Rest Debugger, it tells me that the local css is being delivered as "text/css"  [typo]
If I use a remote server (internet) for the css it renders correctly in both servers.

I have run the standalone as Administrator and still no joy.

Why can't I run local css?[image]

Comment: The [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Common_examples_%5B10%5D) must be `text/css`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code (and changes)

```
  s := Split(Request.PathInfo, '/');
  if s[1] = 'assets' then
    begin
       if (s[2] = 'css') and (fileExists(style + s[3])) then
         begin
         Response.ContentType := 'text/css';
         Response.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(style + s[3], fmOpenRead);
        // page.LoadFromFile(style + s[3]);
        //  Response.Content := page.Text ;
         end
       else
         page.Add(s[3] + ' does not exist!');

       if s[2] = 'js'  then
         page.LoadFromFile(scrip + s[3]);
    end
```

Originally, I was loading the css into a tStringList, and then sending  tStringList.text.  Now I open a filestream to the css.

I don't know *why* this works, but I hope it can help someone else.